# anltr 4 get error message

Tags: exception, antlr4

I am simply trying to get the error message spit out by antlr when an exception happens. To do so I need to catch the RecognitionException and use it to get what I need.

For some reason the following I have put in place are not working.

im using Using antlr 4.1

Inside the grammar:

```
@rulecatch
{
   catch (RecognitionException e)
 {
    throw e;
 }
}   

@parser::members
{
  public void reportError(RecognitionException e)
  {
     throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage()); 
  }
}

@lexer::members 
{   

   public void reportError(RecognitionException e)
  {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage()); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better solution than putting that into the grammar would be writing your own ErrorListener based on the Interface [ANTLRErrorListener](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRErrorListener.html). You can add this to the parser by the following code:

```
parser.addErrorListener(@NotNull ANTLRErrorListener listener);
```

Note that it might be necessary to remove all other ErrorListeners by

```
parser.removeErrorListeners();
```

Possibly the [ConsoleErrorListener](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ConsoleErrorListener.html) fulfill your wishes of posting every Error to the console.